# Forward Request to Azure Service Bus

Tags: java, azure, events, azureservicebus, azure-api-management

I am trying to forward events from Azure API Management to Azure Service Bus but I am getting all time internal errors.

Flow:

```
APIM --> Service Bus Topic --> Service Bus Queue --> Function
```

I added a new entry on the API section (menu right side) on API Management and I added the URL of the topic from Azure Service Bus where I want to publish this event.
After that, I defined a new resource (GET/POST/...).

Only after that, I went to the Test section, I added the Authorization (Sas token from Service Bus) and I make the request. On the phase I got a 500 Internal Error.

Does Anyone know what I am doing wrong to get this error?

Note:
I got the connection between the topic and a queue 100% done and tested, this is working already. The problem is from APIM to Service Bus topic.

I want to expose an API using API Management but at the same time, I want to convert everything to events after that

Comment: You can refer to [Azure APIM as forward proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926448/azure-apim-as-forward-proxy) and [Exposing Azure Service Bus through APIM, generating a SAS Token and setting the Session Id](https://connectedcircuits.blog/2018/09/25/exposing-azure-service-bus-through-apim-generating-a-sas-token-and-setting-the-session-id/)

Comment: Did you check the links mentioned in the above comment? Did you get the solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for ServiceBus Output binding with Azure functions to configure the workflow.

Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sandbox/functions-recipes/service-bus#azure-service-bus-output-binding) to understand more about Service bus bindings.

You can refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607880/how-to-send-data-to-service-bus-topic-with-azure-functions) which gives us insights about the process and the logic (But it is in C#), thanks to George for brief explanation.

As DeepDave Suggested refer to this [blog](https://joeblogs.technology/2021/07/posting-to-azure-service-bus-from-api-management/)